# Unable to use the image ( in ECR ) in K8S cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to pull the image from the ECR repository inside the Kubernetes cluster, but I am not able to do this.

I tried creating a secret and updated in the pod file, but I am not able to do this I am getting an error "no basic auth credentials".

Please can anyone give me the step by step instructions to pull the image from a ECR repository inside the Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Is there any specific error you're getting?

Comment: yes, I am not able to pull the image , When i type describe pods i am getting  Error response from daemon: Get XXX: no basic auth credentials and when i type get pods i am getting ImagePullBackOff error, But i have passed my secrets , Please can you say me how to pass the secrets correctly ?? need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be caused by the fact that ECR credentials work only for 12 hours, so maybe you are trying to use expired credentials.

I recommend you to have a look at [upmc-enterprises/registry-creds](https://github.com/upmc-enterprises/registry-creds). This tool can be installed on your cluster and automatically refresh ECR/GCR credentials before they expire.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can assign an IAM role to the nodes of your cluster to pull the images from ECR. Please find below an example role to pull images from ECR.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```